# Disable volume control overlay on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, audio, user-interface

When changing the volume on a Mac, you get a big ugly gray overlay showing the change in volume. This is super annoying when (say) watching a movie. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 4):

The window itself and the bars that appear on it are dynamically generated by the OS, but if  you're really keen on at least changing or getting rid of the giant speaker icon or any of the other overlays, go to `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/BezelUI/HiDPI/` and there you'll find the directory full of the icons saved, oddly enough, as PDFs.

If you want the speaker icon to disappear, save over volume.pdf with a small blank image in PDF format using Photoshop or some other image editor.

Comment: PDF is resolution independent vector images. Nothing odd about it. E.g. The Panic developers recommend PDF for resolution independent artwork e.g. In Coda IIRC.

Comment: I had expected since it's deep enough in the OS that it would be using an Apple or NeXT format.  That's what I found odd.

Comment: @UtopiaLtd [Quartz 2D - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_2D) and [Display PostScript - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_PostScript) (a really NeXT-y format)

Answer (score -1):

Here I made a custom volume and mute icon, just rename the originals and copy these in place,

public share drive for Mute.pdf and Volume.pdf:

http://sdrv.ms/11XrS5W

Comment: Can you give more details?